# Code in python for arcgis to select multilines (path) and vertexes

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2

I am learning to write Python code for ArcGIS 10.2.

1. I have some shp poly lines file, need to learn how to write multiple selection of those lines, even if a cursor of mouse pressed not exactly on line but near of it.
2. By selecting one vertex, on the cross place of lines should be selected all the vertices.

Any ideas of algorithms and methods, or reading materials?

I am not familiar with programming algorithms, but I know Python.

Comment: (+1 so you can post a picture soon.) Since you are Python proficient, could you please post some pseudo code outlining what you are trying to do? I'm not really sure what you want for 2).

Comment: I am not a good python proficient, studied it by my self on codeacademy.com. For this task I didn't wrote anything yet, just trying to read arcgis 10.2 tutorial about how to write scripts there. A teacher gave me task to write a code for geometric data, by choosing the line (even if cursor wasn't exactly on the line but near of it) the line should be selected anyway. That was first task, it would be good if I could understood how to write it first.

Comment: Are you looking to emulate [Select Features](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000000w000000)?

Comment: yes, but I need to learn write an algorithm for to do that kind of task. where I can see some examples maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Since you expressed that you knew some Python, I think you'll want to design a [Python add-in](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//014p00000025000000).

You can create a [tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Tool/014p00000027000000/) that gives you access to lots of functions that would be useful for selections such as

> onRectangle()--Occurs when the mouse button is released after the rectangle is drawn on the map

Comment: thanks for all answeres!!! will check and try soon all the coments. In matlab i did learn how to write a function "if the pont in polygon or not", is that possible to do that kind of function for ArcGis, with the python help? That will be close to my task.

Comment: @DiGiS, yes you can; I've actually implemented a point in polygon function that I used in a workflow. I used [this code](http://www.ariel.com.au/a/python-point-int-poly.html).